# How can I ensure that an AWS EFS is not mounted on any EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I have to delete several Amazon Elastic File Systems, but they are currently mounted to many EC2 instances.

Now we have to remove these EFS. Is there a way to check from the AWS console which instances are using an EFS?

Comment: Check the instances that are in the AZs of the mount targets, or use AWS CLI